# Spring data jpa from multiple tables

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa. And I have a inner join on two tables. This is my query.

```
SELECT A.NAME, A.CARD_NUMBER, A.ADDRESS, A.EMAIL FROM USER_INFO ABC INNER JOIN USR_DETAIL DEF ON (ABC.ID = DEF.ID) WHERE ABC.ID = '123456';
```

The two table here have no relationship. So one-to-one or many-to-one or many-to-many on the column name doesn't make sense. Can I define entities without relationship? The reason why we are doing a inner join on the two tables here is simply because doing a join on both of them will be a expensive query.

Comment: Your inner join implies a standard one-to-one relation between two tables by primary keys (id column in each). Why this is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

You can define both entities without any kind of relationship and then you can retrieve the data specifying `nativeQuery=true` in the `@Query(..)` annotation in the read method.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ABC.NAME, ABC.CARD_NUMBER, ABC.ADDRESS, ABC.EMAIL " +
               "FROM USER_INFO ABC " +
               "INNER JOIN USR_DETAIL DEF ON (ABC.ID = DEF.ID) " +
               "WHERE ABC.ID = :id", nativeQuery = true)
UserInfoDetails retrieveUserInfoAndDetailById(@Param("id") String id);
```

Side notes:

- In the projection of the query, I correct the alias from `A` to `ABC` as the query was not written correctly. Feel free to edit the projection accordingly to your needs.
- As a return type, I wrote a `UserInfoDetails` class, supposing it will be return something similar. Feel free to change it accordingly to your needs.